# Optimal "Blow up" Configuration

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

Suppose you have three balls glued together. Two are red and one is blue. The system of balls is blown up by an explosion of pure energy (that conserves the center of mass frame) exactly at the center, expending an amount $E$ of energy. If the mass of each of the red balls is $m$, and the mass of the blue ball is $9m$, what is the largest momentum the blue ball can have after the blow up in the center-of-mass frame?

[image]

If the red balls get blown out in equal and opposite directions, the blue ball would, in theory, stay still, and thus have no momentum in the c.m. frame. However, if the red balls get blown out in not-opposite directions, the blue ball will definitely have to have some momentum in the c.m. frame in order to conserve the momentum of the system.

My initial thought was that the maximum momentum would be obtained by having one of the red balls shoot out in one direction, the blue ball shoot out in the opposite direction, and the red ball stay still, as this (in my mind) would give as much energy to the blue ball while still conserving the momentum of the system. However, I don't know if that is the best case.

Comment: Presumably related to [Maximum Momentum of Neutral Pion](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174416/).

Comment: @dmckee It is definitely a branch-off of that problem.

Comment: My thoughts on that problem led me to this one. An answer to this though doesn't necessarily give an answer to the other one. I believe they are different.

Comment: 1. In what way is this question different from the Neutral Pion question?  2. Why have you made different assumptions? In this case that one red particle is stationary, in the other case that the red particles move together?  3. What is your attempt to solve this problem? You did not appear to have much difficulty solving the Neutral Pion problem. Isn't this one easier?